# How to create a new list from property values when grouping items with GroupBy?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using the Newtonsoft package for JSON serialization and currently have this sample code

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string FirstPathSegment { get; set; }
    public string SecondPathSegment { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public void Foo()
{
    var collection = new MyObject[] 
    {
        new MyObject() 
        {
            FirstPathSegment = "a",
            SecondPathSegment = "b",
            Value = "the value"
        },
        new MyObject()
        {
            FirstPathSegment = "a",
            SecondPathSegment = "b",
            Value = "another value"
        },
        new MyObject()
        {
            FirstPathSegment = "a",
            SecondPathSegment = "z",
            Value = "the value"
        }
    };
    
    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection);
    
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

I want to group all those items, the key is the combination of `FirstPathSegment` and `SecondPathSegment`. The problem is that `Value` should be an array containing all the values from the grouped elements. First I tried to use `GroupBy` this way

```
    var foo = collection.GroupBy(
        myObject => myObject.FirstPathSegment + myObject.SecondPathSegment,
        myObject => myObject.Value
    );
```

The actual serialized output of `foo` is

```
[["the value","another value"],["the value"]]
```

The desired output at the end should be

```
[
  {
    "FirstPathSegment": "a",
    "SecondPathSegment": "b",
    "Values": [
      "the value",
      "another value"
    ]
  },
  {
    "FirstPathSegment": "a",
    "SecondPathSegment": "z",
    "Values": [
      "the value"
    ]
  }
]
```

If that's not possible because the keys get merged it would also be fine to have this

```
[
  {
    "Key": "ab",
    "Values": [
      "the value",
      "another value"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Key": "az",
    "Values": [
      "the value"
    ]
  }
]
```

Does someone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by using below statement where grouped key is defined as composite key.

```
var grouped = collection.GroupBy(
                g => new { g.FirstPathSegment, g.SecondPathSegment })
               .Select(g => new 
                              { 
                                   FirstPathSegment = g.Key.FirstPathSegment, 
                                   SecondPathSegment = g.Key.SecondPathSegment, 
                                   Value = g.Select(h => h.Value) 
                              }
                 );
```

Above will do the grouping what you require.

Check this fiddle -- https://dotnetfiddle.net/xqMf2d

The output of above code is

```
[
    {
        "FirstPathSegment": "a",
        "SecondPathSegment": "b",
        "Value": [ "the value", "another value" ]
    },
    {
        "FirstPathSegment": "a",
        "SecondPathSegment": "z",
        "Value": [ "the value" ]
    }
]
```

Comment: To the OP: note that this has the benefit that it doesn't group by the concatenation of the keys but rather a "tuple" (anonymous type) representing them. The former can have issues, for example [ab, c] and [a, bc] would both concatenate to "abc" which is most likely incorrect (that can also be sidestepped by using a seperator within a concatenation, ie "a/bc", though I prefer the anonymous object)